# Add additional camera presets

Tags: camera

In blender we have a `camera presets` selector.

[image: camera presets]

Some of the items are quite old now and there have not been many new additions. How would one go about adding new presets and what information about the camera would be required?

Comment: In addition a look at the code of the presets [Samsung Galaxy S4](https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/master/release/scripts/presets/camera/Samsung_Galaxy_S4.py) as an example shows what settings are assigned the camera by running that preset's code.  Look for the scripts/presets/camera folder of your blender installation.  Can copy paste one of those files into folder and on restarting / or with F8 will have a new preset with the name of the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need the dimensions of the sensor.

Put those on the sensor width or height.

Then use the plus button (+) on the right of the preset to create a new one, and name it whatever you wish.

To delete the presets you don't need, use the minus button.

Presets are a .py file located in the Scripts folder within the blender progra's folder. In windows they would be in

C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.78\scripts\presets\camera.

As an example, this is the preset for a Full Frame camera:

Full_Frame_35mm_Camera.py

`import bpy`

`bpy.context.camera.sensor_width = 36`

`bpy.context.camera.sensor_height = 24`

`bpy.context.camera.sensor_fit = 'HORIZONTAL'`